# SA-CORE-2013-003 - Files directory Not fully protected

Tags: 6, security

I'm using `Pressflow` 6.38 and I'm trying to implement [SA-CORE-2013-003 - Drupal core - Multiple vulnerabilities | Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003) inside of `/etc/httpd/conf.d/pressflow.conf` configuration file, like following:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/(tmp|var/www/html/current/files)">
    # Turn off all options we don't need.
    Options None
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    # Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
    SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
    <Files *>
        # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
        SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
    </Files>

    # If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_flag engine off
    </IfModule>
</DirectoryMatch>
```

however still getting following message in `Status Report` page:

> Files directory   Not fully protected

```
See http://drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003 for information about the recommended .htaccess file which should be added to the files directory to help protect against arbitrary code execution.
```

My environment:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)
# rpm -q httpd php
httpd-2.2.15-55.el6_8.2.x86_64
php-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64
#
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in /etc/httpd/conf.d/pressflow.conf? I don't know if that is the cause of your issue, but the [instructions](https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003) clearly say you should add a .htaccess file inside the files dir.

Comment: @marcvangend, I can do `.htaccess` inside of files directory, but `/tmp`, gets wiped out, so placing `.htaccess` inside of `/tmp` won't work for me...

Comment: I see. Maybe it's possible to choose another directory for temporary storage, one that does not get wiped out? Any dir (eg. `/var/drupal-tmp`) will do as long as it's writable by apache and you configured the correct tmp path in Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quote from [SA-CORE-2013-003 - Drupal core - Multiple vulnerabilities | Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003):

> Additionally, the .htaccess of the temporary files directory and
>   private files directory (if used) should include this command:
>
> Deny from all

instead of using `.htaccess` inside of `/tmp` directory (which can be wiped), I placed following rule inside of my `pressflow.conf`:

```
<Directory "/tmp">
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Please provide a full answer to the question including some descriptions. Just code is not really an answer. Where did you place these files? Is it still in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/pressflow.conf`? Did you change tmp dir?

Comment: This now answers the question. Thanks for editing :)